# Find regular expression in text using Python 3.8

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to extract a list of **borehole numbers** from some text *(just a small bit for now)* using a **regular expression** but can't quite get the **regex** to work as intended.

The format is usually two capitals followed by a number of varying length e.g `BH1, WS01, BH001`

and occasionally ending with *a capital letter* to indicate it has been re-drilled e.g. `BH2301A` is the redrill of BH2301.

The closest I can get is returning a **tuple** but then I need to return just the first value.

```
BH = re.compile(r'\w\w\d+')
BH.findall('4.9.26.9.2  A summary of rotary coring data from White Chalk (South) is provided in Table 37. Downhole geophysics (optical and acoustic televiewers) was undertaken on five boreholes in the LTC Pumping Tests investigation BH2313A, OH03001, OH03002, OH03003, OH04007 and OH04008. Televiewer data provides a more accurate assessment of fracture location and orientation than the associated core logging. This is because the borehole wall is less susceptible to drilling induced disturbance than the recovered core. An automated discontinuity picking algorithm within WellCAD© software was used by the contractor to identify features in the televiewer datasets. ')
['BH2313', 'OH03001', 'OH03002', 'OH03003', 'OH04007', 'OH04008']

BH = re.compile(r'(\w\w\d+(\w)?)')
BH.findall('4.9.26.9.2  A summary of rotary coring data from White Chalk (South) is provided in Table 37. Downhole geophysics (optical and acoustic televiewers) was undertaken on five boreholes in the LTC Pumping Tests investigation BH2313A, OH03001, OH03002, OH03003, OH04007 and OH04008. Televiewer data provides a more accurate assessment of fracture location and orientation than the associated core logging. This is because the borehole wall is less susceptible to drilling induced disturbance than the recovered core. An automated discontinuity picking algorithm within WellCAD© software was used by the contractor to identify features in the televiewer datasets. ')
[('BH2313A', 'A'), ('OH03001', ''), ('OH03002', ''), ('OH03003', ''), ('OH04007', ''), ('OH04008', '')]
```

Is the tuple output the best I can hope for with my regex? Would I need a loop to slice these up to return the first group?

Comment: I like to use regex101.com for regex troubleshooting

Comment: Use `search` instead of `findall`.

Comment: FYI: `\w` includes digits.

Answer (score -1):

Just extracted the first value from the tuples you get:

```
[x[0] for x in BH.findall('4.9.26.9.2  A summary of rotary coring data from White Chalk (South) is provided in Table 37. Downhole geophysics (optical and acoustic televiewers) was undertaken on five boreholes in the LTC Pumping Tests investigation BH2313A, OH03001, OH03002, OH03003, OH04007 and OH04008. Televiewer data provides a more accurate assessment of fracture location and orientation than the associated core logging. This is because the borehole wall is less susceptible to drilling induced disturbance than the recovered core. An automated discontinuity picking algorithm within WellCAD© software was used by the contractor to identify features in the televiewer datasets. ')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I made a new variable called ID from the BH.findall (text) and did [i[0] for i in ID]